# Guide to design protocol for external accessory

Tags: network-protocols, external-accessory

I am designing a protocol for my app to communicate with my external device via EA framework.  Since things are communicating at the byte data level (using NSInputStream/NSOutputStream) I want to make sure the handsaking/communication protocol is both secure and efficient, so any suggestions on guidelines or principles (much like there is a Google style guide to Objective-C) or literature to refer to would be much appreciated.